# Executing code after waiting for time in background (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, time

I'm making a personal assistant like Google Assistant or Siri, and I want the user to be able to set reminders. For example, if they type "Remind me to wash the dishes at 5pm" I would like it to pop up later and remind them. However I also want code to be able to run while waiting, so you could set multiple reminders or check the weather.

time.sleep simply stops the program. I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it with threads but I'm not sure how. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python threading has a [`Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) which does exactly what you ask for:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

def create_notification(time, name):
    delay = (time - datetime.now()).total_seconds()
    Timer(delay, show_notification, args=[name]).start()

def show_notification(name):
    print(f'notification: {name}!')

create_notification(datetime(2034, 1, 1), 'Hello future!')
```

One thing to watch out for is this approach creates a single thread for each event (which doesn't scale well for lots of events). This also suffers from the problem that if the user closes your program, your program crashes, computer shuts down, power loss, etc. you lose all of your notifications. If you need to handle this, then save them to a file. If you need the notifications to show up even when your program isn't running look into solutions provided by the OS like [cronjobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: I'm getting an error: `typeerror: '>' not supported between instances of datetime.timedelta and int`

Comment: Oops! What was happening there was the `delay` was a `timedelta` and `Timer` expected a number (the number of seconds). I made an edit to fix this.